# Prevent popup if current tab url is not permitted in manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm writing a chrome extension and I want to either disable the popup entirely, or present a message if the url of the current tab is not permitted via the v3 manifest's `host_permissions` property.

This is for a dev support tool and we don't want it enabled for the production url. So if I set:

```
"host_permissions": [
  "http://localhost:3000/",
  "https://*.dev.some-site.com/",
  "https://www.uat.some-site.com/"
]
```

...Then if the user is on [www.some-site.com](http://www.some-site.com) (or anywhere else), I want the popup to be disabled.

I can obtain the relevant url easily enough:

```
let [currentTab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
const { url } = currentTab;
const cookieUrl = url.match(/https?:\/\/[^/]+\//)?.[0];
```

...and I can obtain the array of permitted file patterns with

```
chrome.runtime.getManifest().host_permissions
```

But how can I use this *or anything else* to prevent the popup? Also, converting that wild-card into a genuine regex will be a bit of a pain. Isn't there some out-of-the-box method to do all this??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [chrome.declarativeContent](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeContent/) API to enable the action popup for sites in `host_permissions` and disable it everywhere else by default.

When disabled, the icon becomes grayed out. Clicking it will show the built-in context menu, chrome.action.onClicked won't be triggered. The name of the extension in the puzzle-piece menu is also grayed out.

manifest.json:

```json
  "action": {"default_icon": "icon.png"},
  "permissions": ["declarativeContent"],
```

background script:

```js
chrome.action.disable();

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(() => {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
      conditions: chrome.runtime.getManifest().host_permissions.map(h => {
        const [, sub, host] = h.match(/:\/\/(\*\.)?([^/]+)/);
        return new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
          pageUrl: sub ? {hostSuffix: '.' + host} : {hostEquals: host},
        });
      }),
      actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowAction()],
    }]);
  });
});
```

For simplicity, I don't limit PageStateMatcher's [schemes](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/events/#type-UrlFilter).